# Regex for textarea

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I am trying to build a regex for textarea in my angular 8 application. The textarea should allow all characters but should not allow empty character at the start. I have used 3 but both have the following problems:

1. `^(?!\s*$).+`  -- This does not work if user goes to next line in the textarea using enter key.
2. `^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$`  -- This does not work if there is an empty space between 2 words.
3. `^(?!\s*$)[-a-zA-Z0-9' '.,\(\)&+\/]{1,}$` --  This does not work if user goes to next line in the textarea using enter key.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why not just call `.trim()` on the value at the end?

Comment: A regex seems overkill for that. Why not `.trimStart()` on textarea blur or input changes? If not check for a custom validator which is only a custom function returning a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^\S.*(?:\r?\n\S.*)*$/u
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mDRl0u/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\S.*` - a non-whitespace and the rest of a line
- `(?:\r?\n\S.*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line break sequence
  - `\S.*` - a non-whitespace and the rest of a line
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for your help Wiktor but it still fails when you hit enter key

Comment: @Yogesh So you also allow a trailing linebreak? Try `/^\S.*(?:\r?\n\S.*)*(?:\r?\n)?$/u`. Or, if you do not care about CR, ``/^\S.*(?:\n\S.*)*\n?$/u``. If you allow any amount of empty lines, replace `?` before `$` with `*`.

Comment: @Wiktor...no empty space at the start and no empty space at the end. The rest look perfect. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Yogesh Please look at your question: "*but should not allow empty character **at the start**.*" Use `/^\S(?:.*\S)?(?:\r?\n\S(?:.*\S)?)*$/u` to also disallow it at the end.